# How to enable system file access dynamically in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, web-applications

I have a server-side function that produces an output file. My JSP polls to see if the output is available (the process is complete).

Once the output file is available, its passed into a folder that ideally I would like to be accessible via a URL pattern. In the same way, I can access the resources folder statically, I would like the URL:

```
<host>/{appName}/files/{outputfilename}
```

To return the file if the file is saved in the folder `files/`. This isn't a problem statically if the file is available before deployment and included in the war file. However, if I save the file to the folder while the app is deployed, can I make the file accessible to the `web app`?

If so what is the simplest way to handle this? Or do I have to make a rest request and return the file from the controller?

Comment: You can use nginx to make some folder accessible. Nginx config for that is not so hard to understand. Also don't forget about security and User Roles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said,you can use nginx for this. But don't forget that nginx is not only for this!

Example of nginx config for this:

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name example.test;

        root /your/directory/path/files;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/test_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/test_error.log;

        location ~ \.(js|html) {
            include cors.conf;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }


}
```

Don't forget to give nginx access to this directory :)